# How to create a program which gives a factorial of a number in C++

Tags: c++

I am a beginner in C++ language and i want to create a program which gives the factorial of a number which is inputted in the program. Can anyone help me spot the problem in the code?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int factorial(int x){
    for(int i = 1; i < x; i++){
        x = x * i;
    }

    return x;
}

int main(){
    int num;
    cin >> num;
    num = factorial(num);
    cout << num;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a [debugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger) to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @PaulR, can you tell me how to do line-by-line debuggin in visual studio 2019?

Comment: You don't need a debugger. Print the values of `i` and `x` in the loop and think about why `i < x` never becomes false.

Comment: @UditJethva you just select Debug instead of Run and step through the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is horribly wrong:

```
int factorial(int x){
    for(int i = 1; i < x; i++){
        x = x * i;
    }

    return x;
}
```

If `x` is your counter, then you should not be using it also for the output!

Change it to:

```
int factorial(int n){
    int x = 1;
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        x = x * i;
    }

    return x;
}
```

Note that `int` overflows at around 2 billion (platform dependent), so your computation will not continue correctly beyond `n == 12` or so...

Answer (score 1):

Your code with just simple changes.
Loop will execute n-2 times. If input 5 loop will execute 3 times. Out put will 5*4*3*2

```
int factorial(int x)
{ 
    for(int i =x-1; i>1; i--)
    { 
          x = x * i; 
    } 
    return x;
 }
```

Comment: You could improve this answer by explaining what changes you made and why.